# How do I make multiple tableview cells to lead corresponding view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I am making an app with a tableViewController as the initial view controller. It obviously has a list of items in tableview cells. I want each of the tableView cell to lead to a different View controller. Here is an example of my home screen: 
![enter image description here][1]

What I am trying to achieve, for example, is that the tools cell will take me to a View controller with details about tools. And when I click on weapons, it should take me to a view controller with details about weapons. I already have the view controllers set up, but I don't know how to create segues to each view controller. NOTE: I made these cells in code and not in my storyboard. I made an array of items and I used indexpath.row to display them.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is it possible to have a tableView controller leading to another TableView controller THEN a generic detail View controller? @mc01

Comment: Also, Can I have two of those detail view controllers? Lets say for half of them, I wanted to embed in a youtube video and the other half I provided text as the information. @mc01

Comment: And that partly answers my question... If I did use your technique, the how would I create the segues from my main menu(pictured above) to the different view controllers that I wanted? From there I can use your technique to create a detail view controller. @mc01

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55947/discussion-between-steve-sahayadarlin-and-mc01).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nstead of connecting and creating segue from individual cells, you can connect all those segues from the View Controller button, lying below your view in your storyboard. In this case, you will have multiple segues and none of them will be individually connected to cells. And when segues are ready, you can use this method for moving on to the next View Controller depending on which cell is tapped from the tableView.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:nil];
```

You just have to check which cell is tapped and then perform the appropriate Segue on tap.

Look out for the yellow button as shown below your View Screen in your storyboard.

[image]

Drag and drop a segue from that button onto the View Controller that you want to connect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked! I was able to connect a segue from one View Controller to multiple View controllers. Should I use a switch statement to see which tableView Cell was selected and use indexpath.row in the expression? @iCoder

Comment: Yes. Thats Correct buddy. Actually, that is the actual next step. Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This was extremely helpful and what I needed to do to get rid of the segue from the table view cell. Doing exactly what you suggested above and adding this to the tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath...

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
    {

      if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
      {

        rowSelected = indexPath.row
        sectionSelected = indexPath.section

        //Transition to the Set Details VC
        if indexPath.section == 0
        {
            print("Set Details")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue1", sender: self)
        }

        //Transition to the Info Section
        else if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 2
        {
            print("About Page")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue2", sender: self)
        }

        }//End If IndexPath

    }//End DSRAIP
```